# Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am working on a Spring project. I have faced a problem; i cannot connect to mysql driver. 
Here is pom.xml :

```
<dependencies>

  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
 <dependency>
 <groupId>mysql</groupId>
 <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And here is  application.properties code:

```
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stock_produit
 spring.datasource.username=root
 spring.datasource.password=
 spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
 spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc
```

Logcat:

```
   Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
   2019-02-12 01:40:47.353 ERROR 10086 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed.

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 

  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc 

    ...

           Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc 

    ....

        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc 
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:94) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:224) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:176) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:43) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:83) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        ... 43 common frames omitted
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: which database you trying to connect with your application. Please put the drivers accordingly..

Answer (score 4):

In `application.properties` driver class name that you defined is not found in spring data dependency. So,

I think you should try this..

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stock_produit
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

instead of

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stock_produit
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc
```

> **Note**: You trying to connect with mysql database, which requires `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` and it is available in `spring-boot-data` dependency.

Hope this help you out..

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL server 8 and connector j8.0 then use this class name - com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver