# Spring Boot REST - MYSQL connection not working

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

I am trying to follow a simple sample app tutorial to create a spring boot app and connect it to a mysql database. Using IntelliJ ide. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVl6M5ztOu8

Project Structure:

```
src/main/java/com.example.crudSample
src/main/java/com.example.crudSample/controller/ApiController
src/main/java/com.example.crudSample/models/User
src/main/java/com.example.crudSample/repo/UserRepo
src/test/java/com.example.crudSample/CrudSampleApplicationTests.java
```

When I try to run this sample app I get the following error message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
```

**Steps Taken To Run The Program:

1. Create connection in mysql workbench called "restfulapi"
2. parameters are root with localhost port 3306, user is admin
3. Test Connection: Successfully Made MYSQL Connection (was not prompted for a password when clicking)
4. Click on Connection on MySQL Workbench (did not prompt for a password when clicking connection), and create a crudusers schema
5. Run the spring program using the application runner class
6. Received the error message**

pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

application.properties code:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crudusers?useSSL=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

UserRepo Code:

```
package com.example.crudSample.repo;

import com.example.crudSample.models.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

ApiController Code:

```
package com.example.crudSample.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ApiController {

    @GetMapping(value="/")
    public String getPage() {
        return "Welcome";
    }
}
```

User Class Code:

```
package com.example.crudSample.models;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String firstName;

    @Column
    private String lastName;

    @Column
    private int age;

    @Column
    private String occupation;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getOccupation() {
        return occupation;
    }

    public void setOccupation(String occupation) {
        this.occupation = occupation;
    }
}
```

CrudSampleApplicationTests.java code:

```
package com.example.crudSample;

/*
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class CrudSampleApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}

 */
```

Here is the full stack trace:

```
2022-02-27 02:31:19.645  INFO 19172 --- [           main] c.e.crudSample.CrudSampleApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-02-27 02:31:20.419  INFO 19172 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-02-27 02:31:20.471  INFO 19172 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 43 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-02-27 02:31:21.586  INFO 19172 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-02-27 02:31:21.597  INFO 19172 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-02-27 02:31:21.597  INFO 19172 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.58]
2022-02-27 02:31:21.743  INFO 19172 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-02-27 02:31:21.743  INFO 19172 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2020 ms
2022-02-27 02:31:21.829 ERROR 19172 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : Failed to load driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver from HikariConfig class classloader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2626b418
2022-02-27 02:31:21.832  WARN 19172 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
2022-02-27 02:31:21.836  INFO 19172 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-02-27 02:31:21.851  INFO 19172 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-02-27 02:31:21.877 ERROR 19172 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at com.example.crudSample.CrudSampleApplication.main(CrudSampleApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.setDriverClassName(HikariConfig.java:491) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder$MappedDataSourceProperty.set(DataSourceBuilder.java:460) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder$MappedDataSourceProperties.set(DataSourceBuilder.java:355) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder.build(DataSourceBuilder.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:48) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:90) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    ... 36 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Seems like you have a mismatch between the version of `MySQL` and your Driver librairie version. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54641439/cannot-load-driver-class-com-mysql-cj-jdbc-spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

You should add all this lines

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/snapchat?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
jwt.secret={bcrypt}$donald
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=utf-8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.CharSet=utf-8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true
server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8
server.servlet.encoding.charset=UTF-8
server.servlet.encoding.enabled=true
server.servlet.encoding.force=true
```

Could change the name of DB in my case is "snapchat"

you should the add this dependency on pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.23</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by removing the scope tag for the dependency in the pom.xml file and then refreshing the pom.xml file.

Old Code:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

New Code:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should also specify the connector for `mysql`

```
spring.datasource.driver-class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I think this should fix it.